# How to trigger email notification for remaining recipients when someone Declines to Sign (DocuSign)

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

I am new to DocuSign and currently trying to solve the below problem

I have a three step docusign process

1. Creates Document for signature
2. Customer takes action on document
3. The supervisor approves once customer signed the document.

Currently, if the user Accepts and signs the document, it goes to Step 3.

But if User "Declines", STEP 1 is notified by EMAIL and the supervisor at STEP 3 is not.

I am trying to understand how to make the supervisor receive email when Customer DECLINES a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the supervisor at Step 3 have their own DocuSign account?  I think they might need one to be able to receive an email notification when the customer declines - with an account they simply enable this option:

[image]

If they do not have a DocuSign account, then I believe you can still notify them on a Decline but you would have to write the logic in your integration.  For instance, if the customer declines the envelope, then you detect that through code or through the return url, then you can manually send the supervisor an email letting them know which envelope has been declined.

Comment: In my scenario i cannot have account for step 3 as the UCD does not want step 3 to create account. But I will try through code. Thanks for suggestion